# Pass username and password together with HTTP request

Tags: jenkins

In my Jenkins build I am using [httpRequest](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/) like this:

`httpRequest http://my-server.com`

I would like to add username and password authentication as well, something like:

`httpRequest http://my-server.com --username=myUsername --password=myPassword`

I didn't find any information about this on the documentation. Any idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried: `http://myUsername:myPassword@my-server.com` ?

This is the usual way to send authentication data via HTTP

Answer (score 1):

Send the URL like this:

```
http://username:password@your-jenkins-server:port/
```

Just tested it and it worked fine.